# Сравнение считываемой строки с массивом

Tags: c

Берется фрагмент текста считываемый с клавиатуры, и начинает сравниваться по [высота массива][кабинет]

Вот массив(он считывется до сравнивания в другом куске кода)

**Sergey Kotomkin:154:8(952)74-40-70**

**Maks Loxin:84:8(952)74-41-70**

**Andrey Serov:14:8(952)74-42-70**

**Aleks Sagin:14:8(952)509-08-07**

И сам код

```
char vvod[256];
    printf("Поиск по кабинету\n");
    scanf("%s",&vvod);

for (i = 0; i < returnCounter(); i++){
    if(vvod == "%s",tableInfo[i][1]){
printf("%s %s %s",tableInfo[i][0],tableInfo[i][1],tableInfo[i][2]);
    }
        else{
            printf("В этом кабинете никого нет");
        }
    }
}
```

Но на выходе почему то получаю не тот результат который хочу выводит все считая что ввод всегда равен числу в массиве, при введении кабинета 154 должно выводится только **Sergey Kotomkin:154:8(952)74-40-70**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я прочитал 2 раза вопрос и глаз вытек. в С строки сравниваются через strcmp - https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool empty = true;
for (i = 0; i < returnCounter(); i++) {
    if (strcmp(vvod, tableInfo[i][1]) == 0) {
        printf("%s %s %s", tableInfo[i][0], tableInfo[i][1], tableInfo[i][2]);
        empty = false;
    }
}
if (empty) printf("В этом кабинете никого нет");
```